# Joining 100 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, normalization

Assume that I have a main table which has 100 columns referencing (as foreign keys) to some 100 tables (containing primary keys).

The whole pack of information requires joining those 100 tables. And it is definitely a performance issue to join such a number of tables. Hopefully, we can expect that any user would like to request a bunch of data containing values from not more than some 5-7 tables (out of those 100) in queries that put conditions (in WHERE part of the query) on the fields from some 3-4 tables (out of those 100). Different queries have different combinations of the tables used to produce "SELECT" part of query and to put conditions in "WHERE". But, again, every SELECT would require some 5-7 tables and every WHERE would requre some 3-4 tables (definitely, the list of tables used to produce SELECT may overlap with the list of tables used to put conditions in WHERE).

I can write a VIEW with the underlying code joining all those 100 tables. Then I can write the mentioned above SQL-queries to this VIEW. But in this case it is a big issue for me how to instruct SQL Server that (despite the explicit instructions in the code to join all those 100 tables) only some 11 tables should be joined (11 tables are enough to be joined to produce SELECT outcome and take into account WHERE conditions).

Another approach may be to create a "feature" that converts the following "fake" code

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM TheFakeTable WHERE field1=12 and field4=5
```

into the following "real" code:

```
SELECT T1.field1, T2.field2, T3.field3 FROM TheRealMainTable 
join T1 on ....
join T2 on ....
join T3 on ....
join T4 on ....
WHERE T1.field1=12 and T4.field4=5
```

From grammatical point of view, it is not a problem even to allow any mixed combinations of this "TheFakeTable-mechanism" with real tables and constructions. The real problem here is how to realize this "feature" technically. I can create a function which takes the "fake" code as an input and produces the "real" code. But it is not convenient because it requires using dynamic SQL tools evrywhere where this "TheFakeTable-mechanism" appears. A fantasy-land solution is to extend the gramma of the SQL-language in my Management Studio to allow writing such a fake code and then automatically converting this code into the real one before sending to the server.

My questions are:

1. whether SQl Server can be instructed shomehow (or to be genius enouh) to join only 11 tables instead of 100 in the VIEW described above?
2. If I decide to create this "TheFakeTable-mechanism" feature, what would be the best form for the technical realization of this feature?

Thanks to everyone for every comment!

PS
The structure with 100 tables arises from the following question that I asked here:
[Normalizing an extremely big table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758912/normalizing-an-extremely-big-table)

Comment: Somebody else may be able to speak to it,  but I don't know if SQL Server does join removal like postgres, oracle, etc - http://rhaas.blogspot.com/2010/06/why-join-removal-is-cool.html

Comment: So, realistically, the users probably won't want to look at a report containing several hundred columns, correct?  And you could instead identify specific use cases for this data, and make a separate query for each of those use cases which would hopefully require much fewer joins...

Comment: WHy are you trying to do everything in one view? I would expect that with 100 tables I would have hundreds of views and/or storedprocs to get only the data I need for a particular situation. If teh definition fo what the client wants will be differnt every tiem the query is run based on the where clause dynamic SQL is the best way to go.

Comment: What type of user are we talking about and what are they using to build their query?

Comment: your best shot is dynamic SQL, where you join only what you need. see: [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Comment: Honestly, if you need to join 100 tables for a specific view or query, either your database design is faulty, or you should consider breaking third normal form and create some aggregated tables to store the data you're looking for.

Comment: use materialized views. it will surely help in performance. refer to this https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96567/repmview.htm for more details.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The SQL Server optimizer does contain logic to remove redundant joins, but there are restrictions, and the joins have to be [provably redundant](http://msmvps.com/blogs/robfarley/archive/2008/11/09/join-simplification-in-sql-server.aspx). To summarize, a join can have four effects:

1. It can add extra columns (from the joined table)
2. It can add extra rows (the joined table may match a source row more than once)
3. It can remove rows (the joined table may not have a match)
4. It can introduce `NULL`s (for a `RIGHT` or `FULL JOIN`)

To successfully remove a redundant join, the query (or view) must account for all four possibilities. When this is done, correctly, the effect can be astonishing. For example:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.ComplexView
AS
    SELECT
        pc.ProductCategoryID, pc.Name AS CatName,
        ps.ProductSubcategoryID, ps.Name AS SubCatName,
        p.ProductID, p.Name AS ProductName,
        p.Color, p.ListPrice, p.ReorderPoint,
        pm.Name AS ModelName, pm.ModifiedDate
    FROM Production.ProductCategory AS pc
    FULL JOIN Production.ProductSubcategory AS ps ON
        ps.ProductCategoryID = pc.ProductCategoryID
    FULL JOIN Production.Product AS p ON
        p.ProductSubcategoryID = ps.ProductSubcategoryID
    FULL JOIN Production.ProductModel AS pm ON
        pm.ProductModelID = p.ProductModelID
```

The optimizer can successfully simplify the following query:

```
SELECT
    c.ProductID,
    c.ProductName
FROM dbo.ComplexView AS c
WHERE
    c.ProductName LIKE N'G%';
```

To:

[image: Simplified plan]

Rob Farley wrote about these ideas in depth in the [original MVP Deep Dives book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182048), and there is a [recording of him presenting on the topic](http://sqlbits.com/Sessions/Event5/Designing_for_simplification) at SQLBits.

The main restrictions are that foreign key relationships [must be based on a single key](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/510217/support-join-elimination-for-multi-column-foreign-key-constraints) to contribute to the simplification process, and compilation time for the queries against such a view may become quite long particularly as the number of joins increases. It could be quite a challenge to write a 100-table view that gets all the semantics exactly correct. I would be inclined to find an alternative solution, perhaps using [dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

That said, the particular qualities of your denormalized table may mean the view is quite simple to assemble, requiring only enforced `FOREIGN KEYs` non-`NULL`able referenced columns, and appropriate `UNIQUE` constraints to make this solution work as you would hope, without the overhead of 100 physical join operators in the plan.

### Example

Using ten tables rather than a hundred:

```
-- Referenced tables
CREATE TABLE dbo.Ref01 (col01 tinyint PRIMARY KEY, item varchar(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE);
CREATE TABLE dbo.Ref02 (col02 tinyint PRIMARY KEY, item varchar(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE);
CREATE TABLE dbo.Ref03 (col03 tinyint PRIMARY KEY, item varchar(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE);
CREATE TABLE dbo.Ref04 (col04 tinyint PRIMARY KEY, item varchar(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE);
CREATE TABLE dbo.Ref05 (col05 tinyint PRIMARY KEY, item varchar(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE);
CREATE TABLE dbo.Ref06 (col06 tinyint PRIMARY KEY, item varchar(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE);
CREATE TABLE dbo.Ref07 (col07 tinyint PRIMARY KEY, item varchar(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE);
CREATE TABLE dbo.Ref08 (col08 tinyint PRIMARY KEY, item varchar(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE);
CREATE TABLE dbo.Ref09 (col09 tinyint PRIMARY KEY, item varchar(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE);
CREATE TABLE dbo.Ref10 (col10 tinyint PRIMARY KEY, item varchar(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE);
```

The parent table definition (with page-compression):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Normalized
(
    pk      integer IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    col01   tinyint NOT NULL REFERENCES dbo.Ref01,
    col02   tinyint NOT NULL REFERENCES dbo.Ref02,
    col03   tinyint NOT NULL REFERENCES dbo.Ref03,
    col04   tinyint NOT NULL REFERENCES dbo.Ref04,
    col05   tinyint NOT NULL REFERENCES dbo.Ref05,
    col06   tinyint NOT NULL REFERENCES dbo.Ref06,
    col07   tinyint NOT NULL REFERENCES dbo.Ref07,
    col08   tinyint NOT NULL REFERENCES dbo.Ref08,
    col09   tinyint NOT NULL REFERENCES dbo.Ref09,
    col10   tinyint NOT NULL REFERENCES dbo.Ref10,

    CONSTRAINT PK_Normalized
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (pk)
        WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE)
);
```

The view:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.Denormalized
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
SELECT
    item01 = r01.item,
    item02 = r02.item,
    item03 = r03.item,
    item04 = r04.item,
    item05 = r05.item,
    item06 = r06.item,
    item07 = r07.item,
    item08 = r08.item,
    item09 = r09.item,
    item10 = r10.item
FROM dbo.Normalized AS n
JOIN dbo.Ref01 AS r01 ON r01.col01 = n.col01
JOIN dbo.Ref02 AS r02 ON r02.col02 = n.col02
JOIN dbo.Ref03 AS r03 ON r03.col03 = n.col03
JOIN dbo.Ref04 AS r04 ON r04.col04 = n.col04
JOIN dbo.Ref05 AS r05 ON r05.col05 = n.col05
JOIN dbo.Ref06 AS r06 ON r06.col06 = n.col06
JOIN dbo.Ref07 AS r07 ON r07.col07 = n.col07
JOIN dbo.Ref08 AS r08 ON r08.col08 = n.col08
JOIN dbo.Ref09 AS r09 ON r09.col09 = n.col09
JOIN dbo.Ref10 AS r10 ON r10.col10 = n.col10;
```

Hack the statistics to make the optimizer think the table is very large:

```
UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.Normalized WITH ROWCOUNT = 100000000, PAGECOUNT = 5000000;
```

Example user query:

```
SELECT
    d.item06,
    d.item07
FROM dbo.Denormalized AS d
WHERE
    d.item08 = 'Banana'
    AND d.item01 = 'Green';
```

Gives us this execution plan:

[image: Execution plan 1]

The scan of the Normalized table looks bad, but both Bloom-filter bitmaps are applied during the scan by the storage engine (so rows that cannot match do not even surface as far as the query processor). This may be enough to give acceptable performance in your case, and certainly better than scanning the original table with its overflowing columns.

If you are able to upgrade to SQL Server 2012 Enterprise at some stage, you have another option: creating a column-store index on the Normalized table:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX cs 
ON dbo.Normalized (col01,col02,col03,col04,col05,col06,col07,col08,col09,col10);
```

The execution plan is:

[image: Columnstore Plan]

That probably looks worse to you, but column storage provides exceptional compression, and the whole execution plan runs in Batch Mode with filters for all the contributing columns. If the server has adequate threads and memory available, this alternative could really fly.

Ultimately, I'm not sure this normalization is the correct approach considering the number of tables and the chances of getting a poor execution plan or requiring excessive compilation time. I would probably correct the schema of the denormalized table first (proper data types and so on), possibly apply data compression...the usual things.

If the data truly belongs in a star-schema, it probably needs more design work than just splitting off repeating data elements into separate tables.

Comment: . . If the query were written as nested `SELECT`s (`select t.*, (select top 1 val from ref1 where ref1.ref1id = t.ref1id), . . .`), would that help the compiler recognize this situation?

Comment: . . and one more question.  My understanding is that the execution plan for views is created on the first use of the view (as opposed to when they are created).  In this case, would there be a problem with using the unused columns afterwards?  Would the view get a new execution plan?  Or is my initial understanding wrong for this case?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have read some individuals have optimized join-heavy queries using that strategy. If your database requires many joins and there is no way around it, I believe this could be a viable alternative.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you think joining 100 tables would be a performance issue?

If all the keys are primary keys, then all the joins will use indexes.  The only question, then, is whether the indexes fit into memory.  If they fit in memory, performance is probably not an issue at all.

You should try the query with the 100 joins before making such a statement.

Furthermore, based on the original question, the reference tables have just a few values in them.  The tables themselves fit on a single page, plus another page for the index.  This is 200 pages, which would occupy at most a few megabytes of your page cache.  Don't worry about the optimizations, create the view, and if you have performance problems then think about the next steps.  Don't presuppose performance problems.

ELABORATION:

This has received a lot of comments.  Let me explain why this idea may not be as crazy as it sounds.

First, I am assuming that all the joins are done through primary key indexes, and that the indexes fit into memory.

The 100 keys on the page occupy 400 bytes.  Let's say that the original strings are, on average 40 bytes each.  These would have occupied 4,000 bytes on the page, so we have a savings.  In fact, about 2 records would fit on a page in the previous scheme.  About 20 fit on a page with the keys.

So, to read the records with the keys is about 10 times faster *in terms of I/O* than reading the original records.  With the assumptions about the small number of values, the indexes and original data fit into memory.

How long does it take to read 20 records?  The old way required reading 10 pages.  With the keys, there is one page read and 100*20 index lookups (with perhaps an additional lookup to get the value).  Depending on the system, the 2,000 index lookups may be faster -- even much faster -- than the additional 9 page I/Os.  The point I want to make is that this is a reasonable situation.  It may or may not happen on a particular system, but it is not way crazy.

This is a bit oversimplified.  SQL Server doesn't actually read pages one-at-a-time.  I think they are read in groups of 4 (and there might be look-ahead reads when doing a full-table scan).  On the flip side, though, in most cases, a table-scan query is going to be more I/O bound than processor bound, so there are spare processor cycles for looking up values in reference tables.

In fact, using the keys could result in *faster* reading of the table than not using them, because spare processing cycles would be used for the lookups ("spare" in the sense that processing power is available when reading).  In fact, the table with the keys might be small enough to fit into available cache, greatly improving performance of more complex queries.

The actual performance depends on lots of factors, such as the length of the strings, the original table (is it larger than available cache?), the ability of the underlying hardware to do I/O reads and processing at the same time, and the dependence on the query optimizer to do the joins correctly.

My original point was that assuming *a priori* that the 100 joins are a bad thing is not correct.  The assumption needs to be tested, and using the keys might even give a boost to performance.

Comment: I haven't voted either way but I remember reading something in the book "SQL server 2005 practical troubleshooting" by Cesar Galindo-Legaria (from the SQL Server Query Optimiser team) talking about 60 table joins and saying that was really pushing it beyond sensible boundaries in terms of search space for join orders and types.

Comment: I think that creating a huge view is not the answer. Can you even imagine how hard this to debug and how long it is to write? I've never seen anything lk this. Although I've seen many things...

Comment: @Art . . . I'm looking forward to reading your answer.  If you look back at the original question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758912/normalizing-an-extremely-big-table/14759185#14759185, I made the point that the reference tables should be grouped by theme.  There are many problems with 100 joins, but performance is not *necessarily* one of them.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - I have nothing to add and do not have problems with your answer or others. I would not do such thing as creating join or view of 100 tables as I like to keep it simple. I did not see such things at least in the companies I worked for. Maybe some data wareh. companies have such structures... I do not know. I was not serious in my comments, just teasing, kindly...) And another thing, I never downvote anyone even if I disagree. I ask or keep it to myself unlike many others.

Comment: Actually I have found the passage I was thinking of now. And correcting my previous comment that mentioned 60 tables. `If you are joining over 20 tables, chances are the optimizer is not reviewing the entire search space but relying more on heuristics .... we have seen applications that run regular queries dealing with over 100 tables. While it is possible to run such very large queries, you really are stretching the system in these cases and should be very careful going this far`

Comment: @MartinSmith . . . The characteristics of this query are one large table and one hundred tables, claimed to have 15-20 entries each.  Each of these would have a primary key.  I'd be really surprised if the optimizer did anything other than an index search on each of the keys (and my recommendation was to *try* it out before dismissing it out of hand).  Thank you for the quote; it is definitely valuable for cases where the optimizer might have to do an iota of work.

Comment: I agree with this answer. Create the view and then look at performance problems. Based on the original question, the 100 tables are simple lookups with but a few values. When all the other columns are simple datatypes as well rather than text I can't see you having a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your data doesn't change much, you may benefit from creating an [Indexed View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx), which basically materializes the view.

If the data changes often, it may not be a good option, as the server has to maintain the indexed view for each change in the underlying tables of the view.

Here's a good [blog post](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/see-performance-gains-by-using-indexed-views-in-sql-server/6160148) that describes it a bit better.

From the blog:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vw_SalesByProduct_Indexed
 WITH SCHEMABINDING
 AS
      SELECT 
            Product, 
            COUNT_BIG(*) AS ProductCount, 
            SUM(ISNULL(SalePrice,0)) AS TotalSales
      FROM dbo.SalesHistory
      GROUP BY Product
 GO
```

> The script below creates the index on our view:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_SalesView ON vw_SalesByProduct_Indexed(Product)
```

> To show that an index has been created on the view and that it does
>   take up space in the database, run the following script to find out
>   how many rows are in the clustered index and how much space the view
>   takes up.

```
EXECUTE sp_spaceused 'vw_SalesByProduct_Indexed'
```

> The SELECT statement below is the same statement as before, except
>   this time it performs a clustered index seek, which is typically very
>   fast.

```
SELECT 
      Product, TotalSales, ProductCount 
 FROM vw_SalesByProduct_Indexed
 WHERE Product = 'Computer'
```

Comment: Ironically, the data *started* as being totally denormalized.  The original question was about normalizing it, resulting in a very large number of reference tables.  Creating a materialized view ends up back with the original.