# Does it cause a Cartesian join if you include a table nothing is selected from?

Tags: sql, cartesian

Would this be a Cartesian join:

```
select
dog_t.type
dog_t.breed
date_t.date
from
dog_t,
cat_t,
date_t
where
dog_t.date_key=date_t.date_key
```

Would including the cat_t table cause a Cartesian join... because it isn't joined to anything?

Comment: See this question for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14780307/11683

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You need to add `cat_t.date_key=date_t.date_key` to avoid the cartesian join.

But you still have a cross-join problem with tables `cat_t` and `dog_t`. I would say you should union a separated select from each table.

Comment: This is a purely hypothetical example.  I guess I just don't understand why the cartesian happens... does the sql just buffer fields it doesn't need?

Comment: @tylercomp I see your point. But don't you really need it? Imagine if for some dark reason you need the information of `cat_t` implicit on the results (adding redundant occurrences of cat_t rows)

Comment: Yes it is definitively bad practice, it is just curious to me that it actually causes a Cartesian join.  Helps me understand how sql works under the hood a little bit.  Thanks I appreciate the answer!

Comment: Two tables in a query will cause a Cartesian join that is why you have to add a condition. I am trying to say that Cartesian joins is the way sql works.