# Query slows down if a unused join is removed

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a run into a "problem" which I cannot figure out how to solve. I have a query that runs in about 15 seconds, when I then add a join (which is not used in the select), the query actually speeds up to about 4 seconds, even thou nothing from the additional join is selected. I suppose SQL Server chooses a different execution plan which is faster - but how do I force it to choose the fastest query plan each time?

This query takes around 15 seconds:

```
SELECT
    O.Lvl1_Business_Area_Cd
   ,O.Lvl1_Business_Area_Nm
   ,O.Lvl2_Division_Cd
   ,O.Lvl2_Division_Nm
   ,SUM(F.Economic_Capital) AS Economic_Capital
FROM
    Facts.Financials AS F
    LEFT JOIN Dimensions.Customer AS C ON F.Customer_Id = C.Customer_Id
    LEFT JOIN Dimensions.Organization AS O ON C.CRU_Id = O.CRU_Id
WHERE 
    F.Year_Month_Id = 201706
    AND Lvl1_Business_Area_Cd = 6008000
GROUP BY
    O.Lvl1_Business_Area_Cd
   ,O.Lvl1_Business_Area_Nm
   ,O.Lvl2_Division_Cd
   ,O.Lvl2_Division_Nm
```

This query takes around 4 seconds:

```
SELECT
    O.Lvl1_Business_Area_Cd
   ,O.Lvl1_Business_Area_Nm
   ,O.Lvl2_Division_Cd
   ,O.Lvl2_Division_Nm
   ,SUM(F.Economic_Capital) AS Economic_Capital
FROM
    Facts.Financials AS F
    LEFT JOIN Dimensions.Customer AS C ON F.Customer_Id = C.Customer_Id
    LEFT JOIN Dimensions.Organization AS O ON C.CRU_Id = O.CRU_Id
    LEFT JOIN Dimensions.Nace AS N ON C.NACE_Id = N.NACE_Id
WHERE 
    F.Year_Month_Id = 201706
    AND Lvl1_Business_Area_Cd = 6008000
GROUP BY
    O.Lvl1_Business_Area_Cd
   ,O.Lvl1_Business_Area_Nm
   ,O.Lvl2_Division_Cd
   ,O.Lvl2_Division_Nm
```

The only difference between the two queries, is the `LEFT JOIN Dimensions.Nace AS N ON C.NACE_Id = N.NACE_Id`. However nothing from this table is used in the select statement.

Facts.Financials has ~60 mio. rows, Dimensions.Customer ~17 mio. rows, Dimensions.Organization ~25.000, Dimensions.Nace ~1.000 rows.

```
Customer_Id = bigint
CRU_Id = bigint
Nace_id = varchar(4)
```

I have following indecies on the tables:

```
Facts.Financials: Clustered Index (YearMonth, Customer_Id), Non-Clustered (Customer_Id), Non-clustered columnstore index (Economic_Capital)
Dimensions.Customer: Clustered (Customer_Id, CRU_Id), Non-clustered (CRU_Id), Non-clustered (Nace_Id)
Dimensions.Organization: Clustered (CRU_Id), Non-clustered (Lvl1_Cd, Lvl2_Cd, Lvl3_Cd) Include (Lvl1_Nm, Lvl2_Nm, Lvl3_Nm, Lvl4_Cd, Lvl4_Nm, CRU_Id, CRU_Name)
Dimensions.Nace: Clustered (Nace_Id)
```

This is the execution plan for the slow query (15 sec.)

[image: Slow execution plan]
Slow execution plan XML: [Slow execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1WtoQLDW)

This is the fast execution plan (4 sec.)

[image: Fast execution plan]
Fast execution plan XML: [Fast execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkZMimIvb)

Can anyone point me in the right direction of what I am missing? Do I have a wrong index or how can this happen?

I am running SQL Server 2014

Comment: What warning message for Hash Match in first exec plan?

Comment: @KannanKandasamy it shows this warning for both hash matches: `Operator used tempdb to spill data during execution with spill level 1`

Comment: Good, possibly-related, reading:   http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Comment: What is difference in index named customer_t1 idx_3 and idx_2 why different index chosen by optimizer? Does the statistics to these indexes upto to date? What columns both indexes are on?

Comment: what about estimations? Are they similar to actuals?

Comment: @KannanKandasamy idx_2 is for CRU_Id and idx_3 is for Nace_Id. I have tried to rebuild the indexes so I guess they should be up to date.

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev estimation plan looks the same as the actual plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day or two SQL Server has laid out a new query-plan which make the two almost equally fast. Still don't know why.

Afterwards I switched to clustered columstore index on my main table giving me even faster respons time for my queries.

Answer (score 1):

> However nothing from this table is used in the select statement.

But you are using it in join.so the sql server optimizer will choose different plan ,there are some effects of joins explained by [Paul White](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440595/paul-white) here :
[Joining 100 tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780307/joining-100-tables)

So even though you are not using it in the select , a join may have different side effects

> It can add extra columns (from the joined table)
>       It can add extra rows (the joined table may match a source row more than once)
>       It can remove rows (the joined table may not have a match)
>       It can introduce NULLs (for a RIGHT or FULL JOIN)

So if your join doesn't add any of the above side effects, then you may get plan like the other one

Comment: Sure it can add extra columns. But doesn't explain why the optimizer chooses a slower plan when the additional table is not joined?

Comment: adding one more join(in your case left join is faster),this may be due to a different  plans,further can you share both plans as xml  so that we can try on our systems

Comment: Sure - but I am not sure how to attach XML-files without just typing in everything?

Comment: run both the queries with actual execution plan on  and paste them here:https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: Now added below the pictures of the execution plans

Comment: i read your question again,it seems to ask why adding join makes a difference..that was answered,do you want to know how to make 15 seconds query faster  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151302/discussion-between-thegameiswar-and-steffen-sylvest-nielsen).

Comment: Yes and no - I understand that the query plan is different, but I don't understand why it is not able to be equally fast between the two, considering it has to do the same joins except one less.

Comment: My companys firewall prevents me from using the chat - will try to find my personal computer

Answer (score 0):

I am going to take this in a reverse perspective.  You are looking for businesses first and totals for the respective year/month.  Because the field "Lvl1_Business_Area_Cd " is coming from your organization table and that is in the WHERE clause, it forces your query from LEFT JOIN to an INNER JOIN.  Likewise,  the customer table will thus be a required INNER JOIN to the financials.

Now, I would also ensure an index on this field AND the CRU_ID as it is the basis to join to customers... so

```
create index Lvl1CruID on Organization ( Lvl1_Business_Area_Cd, CRU_ID )
```

Similarly for faster join between Customer and Financials

```
create index CruID_CustomerID on Customer ( Cru_ID, Customer_ID )
```

This way the engine does not have to go to the raw data pages to get the join criteria from organization to financials through every record in the customer table.

Finally, your Financials table index on the year/month and customer SHOULD be good.  I moved the criteria to the JOIN instead of the WHERE.

```
SELECT
      O.Lvl1_Business_Area_Cd,
      O.Lvl1_Business_Area_Nm,
      O.Lvl2_Division_Cd,
      O.Lvl2_Division_Nm,
      SUM(F.Economic_Capital) Economic_Capital
   FROM
      Dimensions.Organization O 
         JOIN Dimensions.Customer C 
            ON O.CRU_Id = C.CRU_Id
               JOIN Facts.Financials F
                  ON F.Year_Month_Id = 201706
                 AND C.Customer_Id = F.Customer_Id 
   WHERE 
      O.Lvl1_Business_Area_Cd = 6008000
   GROUP BY
      O.Lvl1_Business_Area_Cd,
      O.Lvl1_Business_Area_Nm,
      O.Lvl2_Division_Cd,
      O.Lvl2_Division_Nm
```

Having good indexes and knowing better how they CAN work is critical, especially passing between multiple tables to get your underlying details.

Now, if you want all organizations even if they DO NOT have any financial activity, you can just change the FINANCIAL join to a LEFT JOIN.

By trying a pre-aggregate approach, this might be better..

```
SELECT
      O.Lvl1_Business_Area_Cd,
      O.Lvl1_Business_Area_Nm,
      O.Lvl2_Division_Cd,
      O.Lvl2_Division_Nm,
      PreQuery.Economic_Capital
   FROM
      Dimensions.Organization O 
         JOIN Dimensions.Customer C 
            ON O.CRU_Id = C.CRU_Id
               JOIN 
               ( select F.Customer_ID, 
                        SUM(F.Economic_Capital) Economic_Capital
                    from
                       Facts.Financials F
                    where 
                       F.Year_Month_Id = 201706
                    group by
                       F.Customer_ID ) PreQuery
                 AND C.Customer_Id = PreQuery.Customer_Id 
   WHERE 
      O.Lvl1_Business_Area_Cd = 6008000
```

Comment: On Organization I actually have two indexes, Clustered (CRU_Id) and Non-clustered (lvl1_cd, lvl2_cd, lvl3_cd) include (lvl1_nm, lvl2_nm, lvl3_nm plus two more levels with code and name). On Customer I have a Clustered Idx (Customer_Id, CRU_Id) and a non-cluster (CRU_Id). So I guess those should be the same as you described - or do you reckon the (Customer_Id, CRU) should be reversed?

Comment: I am trying to create a sort of star-design, and the users are not very SQL-savvy, so I am trying to create it so that the users always can just select from the financials and then add the dimensions they need, rather than the other way around (selecting from organization and left-joining financials). Did that make sense?

Comment: @SteffenSylvestNielsen, your non-clustered on Org not orig listed, but COULD help adding the CRU_ID to it, but lvl1 in first position.  Customer non-clustered also not listed.  Try and see how it runs through.

Comment: yeah I realized - tried to type from my memory - but I missed some of the indexes. I will try to rearrange and se how it runs. Running your query without adjusting my indexes gives me 15 sec. query time.
What I am most curious about is how the code actually runs faster when I join on an additional table that I dont really need.

Comment: @SteffenSylvestNielsen, you MIGHT even want to have the financials as a pre-aggreated subquery grouped by customer so that is done FIRST and results just there for the join on customer ID.

Comment: How does straight_join work in SQL Server? Cannot seem to find any documentation.
Aggregating Financials on Customer_Id first is still around 15 sec.

Comment: @SteffenSylvestNielsen, Disregard straight join... that is MySQL and misread your sql-server tag.. Also revised answer with a pre-aggregate option.